# Crear un formulario de búsqueda con sugerencias autocompletadas con Atlas Search y Django

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, autocompletar

Quiero construir un formulario de autocompletar en una webapp Django. Ya he podido hacer la barra de búsqueda en la que consulto mi base de datos MongoDB pero ¿cómo puedo añadir un autocompletado? He intentado adaptar [un tutorial oficial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3IDlOI0D8-8&ab_channel=MongoDB) que lo hace con Javascript:

`search_similar.html`:

```
{% extends "todo/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

  <div class="recommendations">
    <!-- <div class="login-page"> -->
    <div class="form">
      <form class="form" action="{% url 'similar_results' %}" method="get">
        <input name="q" type="text" placeholder="Perfume name...">
        <input id="perfumename" type ="submit" value="Find Similar Perfumes"/>
      </form>
    </div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#perfumename").autocomplete({
          source: async function(request, response){
            let data=await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/similar/similar_results?q={request.term}`)
            .then(results => results.json())
            .then(results => results.map(result => {
              return { label: result.name, value: result.name, id:result._id };
            }
            response(data);
          },
          minLength:2,
          select: function(event, ui){
            console.log(ui.item);
          }
        })
      })
    </script>
  </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Aunque tenga autocomplete="nope" la primera barra de búsqueda sigue mostrando el autocomplete por defecto de chrome y no muestra el que he construido en MongoDB.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me pregunto si no es un problema en el javascript, pero soy malo en javascript. En efecto la url donde llegamos cuando hicemos cuando pulsamos el botón:

`urls.py`

```
path('similar/similar_results/', views.SearchResultsView.as_view(), name='similar_results'),
```

`views.SearchResultsView`:

```
class SearchResultsView(ListView):
    model = Perfume
    template_name = 'todo/search_similar_results.html'

    def get_queryset(self):  # new
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        print("JE SUIS PASSE PAR LA")
        # object_list = list(collection.find({"q0.Results.0.Name": {"$regex": str(query), "$options": "i"}}))
        object_list = list(collection.aggregate([
                {
                    '$search': {
                        'index': 'default',
                        'compound': {
                            'must': {
                                'text': {
                                    'query': str(query),
                                    'path': 'name',
                                    'fuzzy': {
                                        'maxEdits': 2
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        ))
        print([x["name"] for x in object_list])
        return [x["name"] for x in object_list]
```

Y me devuelve todo lo que necesito:

```
['Not a Perfume - Coffret Noël Not a Perfume', 'Festival Nite Pour Lui – Coffret Noël Eau de Toilette', ... , 'Parfum de Peau - Huile Parfumée Roll-on'
```

A mi parecer es posible que hay el problema en el javascript: `http://localhost:8000/similar/similar_results?q={request.term}`.

## Actualizacion

Intenté con la solucion de Mauricio Conteras pero tengo problemas en el backend (que pienso que soluciono) y el frontend que no he solucionado.

### Backend

Tenia problemas con el backend. En efecto obtengo el siguiente error: `pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Remote error from mongot :: caused by :: autocomplete index field definition not present at path XXX`. Con el siguiente pipeline:

```
pipeline = [
        {
            "$search": {
                "index": "default", # nombre de mi index
                "autocomplete": {
                    "path": "name", #el nombre del field sobre cual hizo el index
                    "query": str(query) # query = self.request.GET.get('q')
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$limit": 10
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                "_id": 0,
                "title": 1
            }
        }
    ]
```

Sin embargo, puse `nombre` como path del *field definition* del index:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero con la original devuelvo lo que necesito:

```
    pipeline = [
            {
                '$search': {
                    'index': 'default',
                    'compound': {
                        'must': {
                            'text': {
                                'query': str(query),
                                'path': 'name',
                                'fuzzy': {
                                    'maxEdits': 2
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "$limit": 10
            },
            {
                "$project": {
                    "_id": 0,
                    "name": 1
                }
            }
        ]
    result = list(collection.aggregate(pipeline))
    data = {'data': result}
    print(data)
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Devuelve:

```
{'data': [{'name': 'Not a Perfume - Coffret Noël Not a Perfume'}, {'name': 'Festival Nite Pour Lui – Coffret Noël Eau de Toilette'}, {'name': 'Festival Nite Pour Ell
e – Coffret Noël Eau de Parfum'}, {'name': "For A Kiss 'Iconic Love' - Coffret Noël Eau de Toilette"}, {'name': 'Daisy Love - Eau de Toilette'}, {'name': 'Crystal No
ir - Eau de Parfum'}, {'name': 'Rose Pompon - Eau de Toilette'}, {'name': 'Candy love - Eau de Toilette'}, {'name': 'Drakkar Noir - Eau de Toilette'}, {'name': 'Quat
re en Rose - Eau de parfum'}]}
```

### Frontend

He intentado mostrar los datos recuperados del backend en una simple alerta:

```
function autocomplete(value) {
      if(!value) return;
      currentFocus = -1;
      url = `/similar/similar_results/?query=${value}`;
      fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        let data= json.data;
        alert(data);}) // <-- Aqui intento muestrar los datos que provienen del backend
      .catch(e => {
        console.error(e.message);
        console.log('Uuuuups');
      });
    }
```

Pero nunca recibo este mensaje.

En el console obtengo:

```
(index):99 Unexpected token < in JSON at position 2
(anonymous) @ (index):99
Promise.catch (async)
autocomplete @ (index):98
(anonymous) @ (index):140
(index):100 Uuuuups
```

Que parece venir de del try catch en el javascript:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## Mea maxima culpa

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que se devuelve es una página html. Creo que uso como endpoint lo que se usa para devolver la página de resultados cuando hizo Enter

Comment: En esta [documentación](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp) hay una forma eficiente de hacerlo.

Comment: ¿Cómo estás enviando los datos desde el backend? El error parece que se refiere a un formato que no es JSON. ¿Podrías verificar que usas `return JsonResponse(data)` en tu `backend`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea hacer una lista de [auto completado](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete) en [html](/questions/tagged/html), de tal forma que la misma contenga los valores de acuerdo a una consulta a una base de datos de [MongoDB Atlas](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/), realizada usando un índice [`autocomplete`](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/autocomplete/) en un proceso de agregación usando el operador [`$search`](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/query-syntax/) (exclusivo de Mongo Atlas).

**SOLUCIÓN**

Una posible solución es usar una llamada [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) o llamada [`ajax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) a nuestro backend, de tal forma que se nos devuelva una lista de elementos que coincidan con lo que se tipea o escribe en el elemento de entrada (`input`) del formulario de búsqueda.

La idea es realizar una petición a la Base de Datos usando como valor de búsqueda el valor del elemento `input`, y generar una lista de sugerencia (auto completado) que coincida con lo que se ha escrito.

Suponiendo que se tiene una velocidad de conexión decente, es posible llevar a cabo la tarea sin muchos problemas.

En este ejemplo usaremos Javascript puro, sin librerías de terceros, excepto para ciertos estilos globales CSS3, que los aplicaremos usando [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/).

**Backend**

Primero vamos a configurar el `endpoint` de nuestro *backend*, escrito en [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/3.1/). No tocaremos la configuración de índices de MongoDB Atlas, ya que se asume que los mismos ya han sido configurados para búsqueda de autocompletado.

Supongamos que usaremos el siguiente `endpoint` que recibe un valor mediante una *Query URL*:

```
/api/entidad?clave=valor
```

En este *endpoint* estamos enviando un par `<clave>=<valor>` en la `url` de la solicitud.

Así, podemos crear la siguiente función en el archivo `views.py` de nuestra aplicación:

```py
from django.http import JsonResponse
from pymongo import MongoClient


user = 'my_user'
pswd = 'my_pass'
mongo_uri = f'mongodb+srv://{user}:{pswd}@xxxx.yyyyy.gcp.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority'

def search(request):
    params = request.GET
    title = params.get('title', '')
    client = MongoClient(mongo_uri)
    db = client.my_database
    pipeline = [
        {
            "$search": {
                "index": "revolucion",
                "autocomplete": {
                    "path": "title",
                    "query": title
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$limit": 10
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                "_id": 0,
                "title": 1
            }
        }
    ]
    result = list(db.collection.aggregate(pipeline))
    data = {'data': result}
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Este es un ejemplo de búsqueda de autocompletado en la base de datos `my_database` usando el índice llamado `revolucion`. Vemos que el `pipeline` de agregación para la etapa `$search` es de tipo `autocomplete`, sobre el campo `title` y usando como elemento de consulta (`query`) el valor obtenido de la `url` de la petición. En este ejemplo, se están limitando los resultados a sólo 10, pero puedes ajustar el valor a un número más alto o puedes eliminar totalmente la etapa `$limit` para que devuelva todos los resultados que coincidan con la consulta.

El resultado de dicha consulta a MongoAtlas se almacena en un diccionario dentro de la clave `data` y luego se envía este diccionario en una respuesta tipo `json` al cliente que realizó la solicitud.

Esto es lo básico de un `endpoint` en Django para realizar la consulta de autocompletado a la Base de Datos y enviar el resultado al cliente.

**Frontend**

Ahora, la parte más complicada está en generar una lista de autocompletado que se actualice de acuerdo a lo que el usuario escribe en el elemento de tipo `input`. Existen diversas formas de lograr el objetivo, pero usaremos una forma básica que implica programación en [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) y conocimiento de [html](/questions/tagged/html) y [css](/questions/tagged/css).

Lo primero es trabajar en la lógica de petición a nuestro `backend`. Para ello usaremos la API `fetch`:

```js
fetch(endpoint_url)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(json => {
  let data = json.data;
  // data contiene la lista de elementos que deseamos usar en nuestra sugerencia
  // de autocompletado.
  // ...
})
.catch(e => {
  console.log('Uuuuups');
});
```

Esta es la forma en que podemos hacer la petición a nuestro `endpoint` en Django. La lógica para escribir el resultado como una lista de sugerencias de autocompletado varía de acuerdo los resultados deseados.

En este ejemplo usaré algunas funciones que se encargarán de dar formato tanto a la lista como al resultado obtenido. Además, usaré una llamada a un `endpoint` que será: `api/movies`. En mi ejemplo usaré la base de datos de prueba que provee Mongo Atlas.

La primera función que vamos a implementar se llamará `autocomplete`, y será como se ve a continuación:

```js
function autocomplete(value) {
  if(!value) return;
  currentFocus = -1;
  url = `/api/movies?title=${value}`;  // <- value: valor introducido en el input
  fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => {
    closeAllLists();
    if(!json.data || !json.data.length) return;
    let listContainer = document.createElement('DIV');
    listContainer.setAttribute('id', 'autocompleteList');
    listContainer.setAttribute('class', 'autocomplete-items');
    autocompleteContainer.appendChild(listContainer);
    let movies = json.data;
    for(let movie of movies) {
      let title = document.createElement('DIV');
      title.innerText = movie.title;
      title.addEventListener('click', e => {
        autocompleteInput.value = e.currentTarget.innerText;
        closeAllLists();
      });
      listContainer.appendChild(title);
    }
  });
}
```

Analicemos esta función en detalle, ya que es la que realiza todo el proceso de generar la lista de autocompletado.

Se recibe un valor, y se establece una variable (que usaremos más adelante), llamada `currentFocus` a -1. Se crea una cadena `url` dinámicamente usando el valor recibido. Se hace la llamada a nuestro `endpoint` usando la `url` generada.

El resultado de dicha llamada se convierte en un objeto de Javascript usando el método [`json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Body/json) del objeto [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Response) recibido. Una vez que tenemos nuestro objeto, llamamos a una función llamada `closeAllLists()` (que veremos más adelante) y procedemos a obtener los datos recibidos.

Se crea un elemento de tipo `div`, y le añadimos un identificador al mismo (atributo `id`), también le añadimos una clase `css` para darle el aspecto que definiremos con los estilos.

Seleccionamos el elemento que contendrá nuestra lista de resultados y le agregamos el `div` que acabamos de crear, como nodo hijo usando [`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).

Por último vamos a recorrer cada elemento de la lista de datos devuelta, y por cada valor (en este ejemplo estamos buscando auto completar el título de una película), vamos a crear un nuevo elemento `div` que contendrá el valor devuelto por la BD. Además, en cada iteración, añadimos un manejador para el evento `click`, para que al hacer clic sobre dicho elemento, el `input` tome ese valor.
Al final, en cada iteración, añadimos el elemento `div` al contenedor de elementos.

Ahora, lo que haremos es darle algo de diseño y por supuesto, acciones para el uso del teclado (usar teclas de dirección arriba y abajo y presionar *Enter* sobre un elemento seleccionado).

Esta lógica se basa casi toda en [este ejemplo](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp) de `w3schools`. Si bien he cambiado algunos detalles, es básicamente el mismo concepto.

La función `closeAllLists()` se encarga de eliminar del nodo contenedor principal los contenedores añadidos, para *despejar* o limpiar el camino para el siguiente grupo de auto completado de acuerdo a lo que se va escribiendo en el elemento `input`:

```js
function closeAllLists() {
  let listElements = document.getElementsByClassName('autocomplete-items');
  // recorre todos los elementos hijos del contenedor de items y los elimina
  for (let i = 0; i < listElements.length; i++) {
    listElements[i].parentNode.removeChild(listElements[i]);
  }
}
```

La siguiente función se encarga de manejar el evento `keydown` cuando estamos escribiendo en el elemento `input` y deseamos seleccionar algún elemento de la lista que se despliega:

```js
function keyDownHandler(event) {
  let items;
  let item = document.getElementById('autocompleteList');
  if (item) items = item.getElementsByTagName("div");
  if(event.keyCode === 40) { // Down (Dirección hacia abajo)
    currentFocus++;
    addActiveClass(items);
  } else if(event.keyCode === 38) {  // Up (Dirección hacia arriba)
    currentFocus--;
    addActiveClass(items);
  } else if(event.keyCode === 13) {  // Enter (Tecla de Intro)
    event.preventDefault();
    if(currentFocus > -1) {
      if(items) {
        items[currentFocus].click();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Las siguientes 2 funciones se encargan de establecer los estilos o retirarlos según un elemento se encuentre seleccionado (`currentFocus`):

```js
function addActiveClass(items) {
  if (!items) return;
  removeActiveClass(items);
  if (currentFocus >= items.length) currentFocus = 0;
  if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (items.length - 1);
  items[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
}

function removeActiveClass(items) {
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
  }
}
```

Por último, debemos manejar los eventos `input` y `keydown` sobre nuestro elemento de texto, para que se ejecuten las acciones necesarias y se realice la búsqueda a BD del texto para el auto completado, además se añade un manejador para el evento "click" sobre cualquier sitio del documento diferente al `input`, para que el panel de auto completado se oculte.

```js
autocompleteInput.addEventListener('input', e => {
  closeAllLists();
  autocomplete(e.currentTarget.value);
});

autocompleteInput.addEventListener('keydown', keyDownHandler);

document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  closeAllLists();
});
```

La implementación casi completa del HTML con los estilos y el script se puede apreciar en el siguiente código:

```html
  <!-- ESTILOS DE BOOTSTRAP -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- ESTILOS PROPIOS -->
  <style>
    .autocomplete-items {
      position: absolute;
      border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
      border-bottom: none;
      border-top: none;
      z-index: 99;
      /*position the autocomplete items to be the same width as the container:*/
      top: 100%;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
    .autocomplete-items div {
      padding: 10px;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: #fff;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
    }
    .autocomplete-items div:hover {
      /*when hovering an item:*/
      background-color: #e9e9e9;
    }
    .autocomplete-active {
      /*when navigating through the items using the arrow keys:*/
      background-color: DodgerBlue !important;
      color: #ffffff;
    }
  </style>
  <!-- PLANTILLA HTML (FORMULARIO) -->
  <div class="container-fluid mt-3">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-6">
        <p class="lead text-center">
          {{ page_title }}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-8">
        <form autocomplete="off">
          <div id="autocompleteContainer" class="input-group mb-3 autocomplete">
            <input id="autocompleteInput" type="text" class="form-control autocomplete" placeholder="Movie title" aria-label="Movie title search" aria-describedby="searchButton">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="searchButton">Search</button>
          </div>
          <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- JAVASCRIPT -->
  <script>
    let currentfocus;
    let autocompleteContainer = document.getElementById('autocompleteContainer');
    let autocompleteInput = document.getElementById('autocompleteInput');

    function closeAllLists() {
      let listElements = document.getElementsByClassName('autocomplete-items');
      for (let i = 0; i < listElements.length; i++) {
        listElements[i].parentNode.removeChild(listElements[i]);
      }
    }

    function autocomplete(value) {
      if(!value) return;
      currentFocus = -1;
      url = `/api/movies?title=${value}`;
      fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        closeAllLists();
        if(!json.data || !json.data.length) return;
        let listContainer = document.createElement('DIV');
        listContainer.setAttribute('id', 'autocompleteList');
        listContainer.setAttribute('class', 'autocomplete-items');
        autocompleteContainer.appendChild(listContainer);
        let movies = json.data;
        for(let movie of movies) {
          let title = document.createElement('DIV');
          title.innerText = movie.title;
          title.addEventListener('click', e => {
            autocompleteInput.value = e.currentTarget.innerText;
            closeAllLists();
          });
          listContainer.appendChild(title);
        }
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.error(e.message);
        console.log('Uuuuups');
      });
    }

    function keyDownHandler(event) {
      let items;
      let item = document.getElementById('autocompleteList');
      if (item) items = item.getElementsByTagName("div");
      if(event.keyCode === 40) { // Down
        currentFocus++;
        addActiveClass(items);
      } else if(event.keyCode === 38) {  // Up
        currentFocus--;
        addActiveClass(items);
      } else if(event.keyCode === 13) {  // Enter
        event.preventDefault();
        if(currentFocus > -1) {
          if(items) {
            items[currentFocus].click();
          }
        }
      }
    }

    function addActiveClass(items) {
      if (!items) return;
      removeActiveClass(items);
      if (currentFocus >= items.length) currentFocus = 0;
      if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (items.length - 1);
      items[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
    }

    function removeActiveClass(items) {
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        items[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
      }
    }

    autocompleteInput.addEventListener('input', e => {
      closeAllLists();
      autocomplete(e.currentTarget.value);
    });

    autocompleteInput.addEventListener('keydown', keyDownHandler);

    document.addEventListener('click', e => {
      closeAllLists();
    });
  </script>
```

El resultado de esta implementación se puede observar en la siguiente [aplicación Django](https://revolucion.herokuapp.com/api/) subida a Heroku.

**Nota**

Cabe destacar, que para que este código funcione correctamente, se debe establecer la propiedad `autocomplete` del formulario a `off`:

```
autocomplete="off"
```

De lo contrario, el navegador llenará con los datos del historial de auto completado local, su propia lista de auto completado.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias Mauricio. He actualizado mi pregunta. Tuve un problema con la petición del backend al índice pero creo que lo solucioné. Pero creo que todavía tengo un problema con el frontend.

Answer (score 2):

La forma más sencilla que pude encontrar es la de usar la [API de jQuery](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/), solo necesitas importar jQuery min y el CSS/JS de jQuery UI.

Acá te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    var perfumes = ["dior","pacco","moschino"];
    
    $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({source: perfumes, minLength: 0}).focus(function(){
        /* Muestra todas las opciones al enfocar el input */
        $(this).autocomplete('search', $(this).val())
    });

});
```

```html
<!-- jQuery-UI CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css"/>


<form class="form" action="#" method="get" autocomplete="off">
    <input id="autocomplete" type="text" placeholder="Perfume name...">
    <input id="perfumename" type="submit" value="Find Similar Perfumes"/>
</form>


<!-- jQuery-Min JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- jQuery-UI JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Puedes cambiar el tema CSS de la API por uno de los siguientes:

- base: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css
- black-tie: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css
- blitzer: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css
- cupertino: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css
- dark-hive: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/dark-hive/jquery-ui.css
- dot-luv: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/dot-luv/jquery-ui.css
- eggplant: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/eggplant/jquery-ui.css
- excite-bike: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/excite-bike/jquery-ui.css
- flick: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/flick/jquery-ui.css
- hot-sneaks: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/hot-sneaks/jquery-ui.css
- humanity: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/humanity/jquery-ui.css
- le-frog: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/le-frog/jquery-ui.css
- mint-choc: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/mint-choc/jquery-ui.css
- overcast: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/overcast/jquery-ui.css
- pepper-grinder: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/pepper-grinder/jquery-ui.css
- redmond: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css
- smoothness: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css
- south-street: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/south-street/jquery-ui.css
- start: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/start/jquery-ui.css
- sunny: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/sunny/jquery-ui.css
- swanky-purse: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/swanky-purse/jquery-ui.css
- trontastic: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/trontastic/jquery-ui.css
- ui-darkness: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css
- ui-lightness: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css
- vader: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/vader/jquery-ui.css

<sub>[Referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13314050/13508115) de donde fue tomada esta lisa</sub>

También puedes crear un estilo personalizado basándote en alguno de los temas ya existentes, una forma podría ser la de crear tu proprio archivo CSS y copiar el contenido de alguno de estos links, para modificarlo sucesivamente.

Comment: Muchas gracias Ariel! Sabes como ¿hacer que este autocomplecion busque en la base de datos a partir de un determinado número de letras?

Comment: No entiendo lo que quieres decir con "buscar un determinado número de letras", el auto-completado debe completar lo que se escribe usando las opciones disponibles que más se asemejen. Puedes usar jinja2 para pasar las palabras que tengas en tu base de datos desde tu backend al frontend, pero no debes hacer que el frontend "hable" directamente con la base de datos. Recomiendo añadirlas en un atributo "data" del input que luego obtengas con jQuery.

Comment: Me disculpes, queria utilisar `minLength: X` para autocompletar a partir de un determinado número de letras. Creo que he hecho lo que me has aconsejado, he puesto los resultados en `data` pero no puedo visualizarlos en `id="autocomplete"`

Comment: Debes asegurarte de que la los datos de jinja2 se carguen en la página antes de que se ejecute la función jquery de autocompletado. De lo contrario al ejecutarse la variable data estará vacía.

Comment: @ArielMontes, modifica la respuesta para usar la URL como fuente de datos: `source: \`http://localhost:8000/similar/similar_results/?query=${request.term}\`,`. Referencia: https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Comment: Puedes editarla tu directamente, no entendí muy bien esa parte en la documentación.

Comment: He creado un archivo json en un repositorio para que puedas usarlo en el source: [perfumes.json](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Ariel-MN/93efe8d2cf69c7b7822e6ae3b219ca2b/raw/b6664735c6e9a15394ff0254e366302ec1c5a4b1/perfumes.json)

Comment: Muchas gracias, no había visto los nuevos comentarios, perdón por el retraso. Gracias por este archivo, pero me molesta un poco porque los nombres de los perfumes de mi base de datos van a evolucionar y preferiría que las sugerencias estuvieran vinculadas. Por lo momento no me devuelve nada cuando no es una variable en el source como la tuya. Por otro lado he intentado poner `alert(thing)` antes, durante y después de `#autocomplete` pero extrañamente no devuelve nada durante la consulta de datos del lado del servidor. Voy a puestar mi codigo al dia con la ultimo intento

Answer (score 2):

Estás recibiendo error al interpretar a JSON porque las propiedades y valores están encerradas entre comillas simples y deberían estar entre comillas dobles. Referencia: https://www.json.org/json-es.html

Debes corregir esto desde el *backend*. No conozco Python, pero la respuesta de @MauricioContreras me parece más que adecuada, revisa la última línea: `return JsonResponse(data)` y tú tienes solo `print(data)`. Supongo que solo hay que incluir la librería correspondiente e imprimir en lugar de devolver.

Ya sea que te bases en la respuesta de Mauricio o en este [tutorial](https://geekytheory.com/como-utilizar-json-en-python), lo ideal es devolver desde el servidor una cadena que contenga un JSON válido.

**Solo como última opción, puedes intentarlo en *frontend***

Probando primero con los datos publicados en tu pregunta:

```js
let str = `{'data': [{'name': 'Not a Perfume - Coffret Noël Not a Perfume'}, {'name': 'Festival Nite Pour Lui – Coffret Noël Eau de Toilette'}, {'name': 'Festival Nite Pour Elle – Coffret Noël Eau de Parfum'}, {'name': "For A Kiss 'Iconic Love' - Coffret Noël Eau de Toilette"}, {'name': 'Daisy Love - Eau de Toilette'}, {'name': 'Crystal Noir - Eau de Parfum'}, {'name': 'Rose Pompon - Eau de Toilette'}, {'name': 'Candy love - Eau de Toilette'}, {'name': 'Drakkar Noir - Eau de Toilette'}, {'name': 'Quatre en Rose - Eau de parfum'}]}`;

// Esta cadena es la única que está bien y hay que conservar
// "For A Kiss 'Iconic Love' - Coffret Noël Eau de Toilette"

// Remplazar comillas simples por dobles, al inicio y final de cadenas
str = str.replaceAll("{'", '{"');
str = str.replaceAll("':", '":');
str = str.replaceAll(": '", ': "');
str = str.replaceAll("'}", '"}');

// Ya se puede interpretar como JSON
console.log(JSON.parse(str));
```

Ahora, adaptado a petición AJAX, debes obtener el resultado como texto para poder aplicar los cambios e interpretar como JSON:

```
function autocomplete(value) {
    if(!value) return;
    currentFocus = -1;
    url = `/similar/similar_results/?query=${value}`;
    fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.text()) // Devolver solo texto
    .then(str => {
        // Aplicar remplazos
        str = str.replaceAll("{'", '{"');
        str = str.replaceAll("':", '":');
        str = str.replaceAll(": '", ': "');
        str = str.replaceAll("'}", '"}');
        // Interpretar JSON
        let json = JSON.parse(str);

        let data= json.data;
        // Alert podría mostrar solo [Object Object] o similar
        // Usa la consola para verificar los datos
        console.log(data);

        // Ahora puedes recorrer con
        data.forEach(item => {
            // Acceder al nombre de cada elemento
            let name = item.name;
        });
    })
    .catch(e => {
        console.error(e.message);
        console.log('Uuuuups');
    });
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, sospeché que habia algun problema de este tipo. Sin embargo [parece que `.then(str` contiene la pagina html](https://i.ibb.co/dDBT1Pp/image.png) en lugar de los datos. Creo que soy yo el que se equivoca y debería haber hecho un endpoint aparte de la página que devuelvo cuando quiero consultar los datos.

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica. como dije en la respuesta, lo ideal es corregir el problema desde el _backend_ y, **solo como última opción**, hacer ajustes en el _frontend_. Revisa nuevamente la respuesta de Mauricio, esa es la que va en la dirección correcta.