# ¿Cómo recuperar datos de una base de datos MongoDB en un javascript?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Estoy intentando que se muestren en un autocompletado pero no se muestra nada del base de datos (digame si es necesario que comparto mi logins).

Me disculpe si lo hizo mal, soy un noob en JavaScript.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
  const uri = "mongodb+srv://user:password@cluster0.n2hnd.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
  const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
  client.connect(err => {
    const collection = client.db("test").collection("sephora_backup3");
    var perfumes = collection.find({});
    client.close();
  });
  $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({source: perfumes, minLength: 0}).focus(function(){
      /* Muestra todas las opciones al enfocar el input */
      $(this).autocomplete('search', $(this).val())
  });
});
```

```html
   

  <div class="recommendations">
    <!-- <div class="login-page"> -->
    <div class="form">
      <form class="form" action="{% url 'similar_results' %}" method="get" autocomplete="off">
        <input id="autocomplete" type="text" placeholder="Perfume name...">
        <input id="perfumename" type="submit" value="Find Similar Perfumes"/>
      </form>
    </div>
    <!-- jQuery-UI CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <!-- jQuery-Min JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- jQuery-UI JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </div>
```

Intento hacerlo aquí porque me pareció muy conveniente poder hacer algo tan simple como:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    var perfumes = ["dior","pacco","moschino"];
    
    $("#autocomplete").autocomplete({source: perfumes, minLength: 0}).focus(function(){
        /* Muestra todas las opciones al enfocar el input */
        $(this).autocomplete('search', $(this).val())
    });

});
```

```html
<!-- jQuery-UI CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css"/>


<form class="form" action="#" method="get" autocomplete="off">
    <input id="autocomplete" type="text" placeholder="Perfume name...">
    <input id="perfumename" type="submit" value="Find Similar Perfumes"/>
</form>


<!-- jQuery-Min JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- jQuery-UI JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Pero si no funciona, no hay problema. Es que [tengo problemas para hacerlo del lado del servidor con Django.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/432191/crear-un-formulario-de-b%C3%BAsqueda-con-sugerencias-autocompletadas-con-atlas-search)

Comment: Que? Porque hay jquery? Y como es que estás tratando de importar mongo del lado del cliente? Ponele que estás usando electrón con nodeintegration que no creo porque creo que el error está en que quieres usar require del lado del cliente, y require no es soportado en cliente side, si quieres usar mongo con js tienes que hacerlo con node, del lado del servidor, un saludo.

Comment: Hay algunas librerías cliente side como minimongo para trabajar con el localstorage del lado del cilente

Comment: @DєηyηCrawford Haa, ¡muchas gracias! Sí, estoy intentando hacerlo aquí porque he visto que alguien lo ha hecho en el ejemplo que acabo de compartir. Estoy tratando de hacerlo en el lado del cliente porque [estoy teniendo problemas para hacerlo en el lado del servidor con Django](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/432191/crear-un-formulario-de-b%c3%basqueda-con-sugerencias-autocompletadas-con-atlas-search)

Comment: @DєηyηCrawford ¿Minimongo? ¡No lo conocia!

Comment: Ojo minimongo no es mongo, simula la API de mongo del lado del cliente con el localstorage, ningún dato está siendo guardado en el servidor, todo se guarda en el navegador del cliente.